# Angular build error "..has no exported member 'ɵReflectorReader'."

Tags: angular, nodemon

Anybody know what causing this build error?

`ERROR in /Users/bv/Documents/GDPTAngular/gdpt/node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/compile_metadata.d.ts (8,109): Module '"/Users/bv/Documents/GDPTAngular/gdpt/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵLifecycleHooks'.`

`ERROR in /Users/bv/Documents/GDPTAngular/gdpt/node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/template_parser/template_ast.d.ts (8,27): Module '"/Users/bv/Documents/GDPTAngular/gdpt/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵLifecycleHooks'.`

`ERROR in /Users/bv/Documents/GDPTAngular/gdpt/node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/directive_resolver.d.ts (8,27): Module '"/Users/bv/Documents/GDPTAngular/gdpt/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵReflectorReader'.`

`ERROR in /Users/bv/Documents/GDPTAngular/gdpt/node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/ng_module_resolver.d.ts (8,26): Module '"/Users/bv/Documents/GDPTAngular/gdpt/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵReflectorReader'.`

`ERROR in /Users/bv/Documents/GDPTAngular/gdpt/node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/pipe_resolver.d.ts (8,22): Module '"/Users/bv/Documents/GDPTAngular/gdpt/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵReflectorReader'.`

`ERROR in /Users/bv/Documents/GDPTAngular/gdpt/node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/metadata_resolver.d.ts (8,75): Module '"/Users/bv/Documents/GDPTAngular/gdpt/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵReflectorReader'.`

`ERROR in /Users/bv/Documents/GDPTAngular/gdpt/node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/aot/static_reflector.d.ts (8,10): Module '"/Users/bv/Documents/GDPTAngular/gdpt/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵReflectorReader'.`

Comment: can u pls tell us what changes made by you triggered this error ?

Comment: it looks like it is trying to load resources from '@angular/core/core' instead of '@angular/core'. We will need more info. What do your import statements look like? are you using webpack?

Comment: Has this been resolved? I am having the same issue. Should I make a new question since this thread seems to have died?

Answer (score 3):

I had this error. Update your package.json

```
 "@angular/common": "4.1.3",
 "@angular/compiler": "4.1.3",
 "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.1.3",
 "@angular/core": "4.1.3",
```

and npm install.

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me when I updated my angular-cli to version 1.3.0, @horus solution solved my problem.

Just in case, delete your node_modules folder and do a fresh "npm install".

Comment: Thanks Karma, npm install fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Got the exact same error message. My build problem manifested in quay (docker registry). Problem was a dash (^) in angular core package. After removal of the dash, errors went away and build went through.